# How to convert my query to CDbCriteria with AND condition?

Tags: mysql, yii

How to convert custom query into CDbCriteria in YIi. I have try like this, maybe not complete:

```
 $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
 $criteria->select='t.kode, t.status, p.berlaku_punish AS p_berlakupunish,p.nilai AS p_nilai';
 $criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN punish p ON (p.id_status = t.id)';

 myquery : `$sql="SELECT status.id, status.kode, status.status, m1.berlaku_punish, m1.nilai
    FROM STATUS LEFT JOIN punish m1 ON status.id = m1.id_status
    AND m1.id = ( SELECT MAX( m2.id ) FROM punish m2 WHERE m2.id_status = status.id)";`
```

How to insert **AND** in myquery into my custom not complete CDbCriteria ??
Sory,about my english.

Comment: Add it just like you added the first condition in `on (...)`

Comment: like this?? $criteria->condition=" t.id IN
(  SELECT MAX( m2.id ) FROM punish m2 WHERE m2.id_status = t.id)";

Comment: show error massage.. 
The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `status` `t` LEFT JOIN punish p on (p.id_status = t.id) WHERE t.id IN ( SELECT MAX( m2.id ) FROM punish m2 WHERE m2.id_status = t.id)

Comment: in this error massage : show Where.. like above

Comment: I think you better go with command builder, this way your much more flexible

Comment: Yes, with CSqlDataProvider, its was ok. but Cgridview for filter, sort not support. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addCondition` like this:

```
$criteria->addCondition("function_id =ur_value");
$criteria->addCondition("legal_id =ur_value");
```

It will define where `function_id=ur_value` and `legal_id=ur_value`

or you can use condition like this:

```
$criteria->condition="function_id=ur_value AND legal_id=ur_value";
```